# Progress bar animation not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

Progress bar animation not working in IE

```
$(".cvss-score").each(function (e) {
       var t = new ProgressBar.Circle(this, {
       color: s,
       easing: "easeInOut",
       strokeWidth: "5",
       duration: 3500,
       text: {
              value: "0"
             }
});
```

IE in giving error 'ProgressBar' is undefined

As I checked with old qstns on same it tells to make strokeWidth less than 6, but still its not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you specify what library you're using it might help...

Comment: I am using https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js

Comment: The linked page seems to work fine in IE11. How exactly have you loaded the scripts?

Comment: Maybe you should try some polyfill

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a test with Example below may help to solve your issue.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>ProgressBar.js - Minimal Example</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <style>
            .progress {
                height: 300px;
            }
            .progress > svg {
                height: 100%;
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>

        <!-- These are probably out dated so you might want to use newest versions -->
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/0.5.6/dist/progressbar.js"></script>

        <script>
 window.onload = function onLoad() {
    var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#progress', {
        color: '#FCB03C',
 strokeWidth: 4,
   trailWidth: 1,
        duration: 3000,
        easing: 'easeInOut',
 text: {
              value: "0"
             }
    });
  
    circle.animate(1);
};
 </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output in Internet Explorer 11:

[image]